# NDSolve problem with describing thermodynamical evolution of a box

Tags: differential-equations

I use the following code to try and model 2D convection in time,

```
P = ρ[x, y, t]/(μ mu) kb T[x, y, t]  ;
e = P/(γ - 1);
cp = 5/2 kb/(μ mu);
Rgas = 8.3144598;
cv = 5/2 kb/(μ mu) - Rgas;
γ = cp/cv;
g = 28.02*9.81;
μ = 0.6163328197226503`;
mu = 1.66053904*10^-27;
kb = 1.38064852*10^-23;
NDSolve[{
D[ρ[x, y, t]*u[x, y, t], 
t] == -D[ρ[x, y, t]*(u[x, y, t])^2 + P, x],
D[ρ[x, y, t]*v[x, y, t], 
t] == -D[ρ[x, y, t]*(v[x, y, t])^2 + P, y] + 
g ρ[x, y, t],
D[ρ[x, y, t], t] == -D[ρ[x, y, t]*u[x, y, t], x] - 
D[ρ[x, y, t]*v[x, y, t], y],
D[e[x, y, t], t] == -D[u[x, y, t]*e[x, y, t], x] - 
D[v[x, y, t]*e[x, y, t], y] - 
P[x, y, t]*(D[u[x, y, t], x] - D[v[x, y, t], y]),

v[0, y, t] == v[12000000, y, t], u[0, y, t] == u[12000000, y, t], 
T[0, y, t] == 
T[12000000, y, t], ρ[0, y, t] == ρ[12000000, y, t],
D[u[x, y, t], y] /. y -> 4000000 == 0, 
D[u[x, y, t], y] /. y -> 0 == 0, v[x, 4000000, t] == 0, 
v[x, 0, t] == 0,
D[T[x, y, 0], y] == 0.41 g ρ [x, y, 0] T[x, y, 0]/P[x, y, 0], 
D[P[x, y, 0], y] == g ρ[x, y, 0], 
T[x, 0, 0] == 5770, ρ[x, 0, 0] == 1.42*10^-7*1.408*10^3
}, {u, v, 
T, ρ}, {{x, 0, 12000000}, {y, 0, 4000000}, {t, 0, 100}}]
```

When evaluating this I get the following error

```
    NDSolve::dsvar: 0 cannot be used as a variable.
```

Is that because I use `u[x,y,0]` and NDSolve sees the zero as a variable or are there other problems?

Comment: Your last two initial conditions, `T[x, 0, 0] == 5770, \[Rho][x, 0, 0] == 1.42*10^-7*1.408*10^3` specify two variables to be zero, not just one.

Comment: Oh, and your two initial conditions on $u_y$ need a parenthesis around the replacement rule.

Comment: And you define `P` with no arguments, and then later try and give it three arguments.

Comment: Oh, and finally the arguments at the end should not be in a list, this is what is causing the specific error message.

Comment: This question has been answered(and some more) by KraZug, thank you

Comment: When I solve the bottom three problems I get to the first one, do you know how I can define values for the edges at t=0?

Comment: @KraZug Would you like to sum up your comments in an answer? Or was it a simple mistake?

Comment: @Kuba, Well, it was still not running once I fixed all those issues, because Mathematica complained about the equations having nonlinear coefficients. It is possible that it is easy to fix that by specifying a different scheme for the discretization, but I don't know much about those.

Comment: @KraZug I only got that error when I deleted the T and \[Rho] initial conditions, but I looked on the site and somebody said(with a different problem) that it is because there are insufficient initial conditions.

Comment: @HiddeRinsema, yes, I have a different error at the moment. See the "answer" - which isn't really an answer

Comment: @KraZug As you said in your answer, the problem is in the fact that the equations don't have a second order derivative in it, I think I might forgot an equation here, since that specific boundary condition is rather important.

Answer (score 1):

After fixing up the obvious typos, you get to:

```
cp = 5/2 kb/(μ mu);
Rgas = 8.3144598;
cv = 5/2 kb/(μ mu) - Rgas;
γ = cp/cv;
g = 28.02*9.81;
μ = 0.6163328197226503`;
mu = 1.66053904*10^-27;
kb = 1.38064852*10^-23;
P[x_, y_, t_] = ρ[x, y, t]/(μ mu) kb T[x, y, t];
e[x_, y_, t_] = P[x, y, t]/(γ - 1);

eqns = {D[ρ[x, y, t]*u[x, y, t], t] == -D[ρ[x, y, t]*(u[x, y, t])^2 + P[x, y, t], x],  
    D[ρ[x, y, t]*v[x, y, t], t] == -D[ρ[x, y, t]*(v[x, y, t])^2 + P[x, y, t], y] +  g ρ[x, y, t], 
    D[ρ[x, y, t], t] == -D[ρ[x, y, t]*u[x, y, t], x] - D[ρ[x, y, t]*v[x, y, t], y], 
    D[e[x, y, t], t] == -D[u[x, y, t]*e[x, y, t], x] - D[v[x, y, t]*e[x, y, t], y] - P[x, y, t]*(D[u[x, y, t], x] - D[v[x, y, t], y])}

bcs = {v[0, y, t] == v[12000000, y, t], u[0, y, t] == u[12000000, y, t], 
       T[0, y, t] == T[12000000, y, t], ρ[0, y, t] == ρ[12000000, y, t], 
       (D[u[x, y, t], y] /. y -> 4000000) == 0, (D[u[x, y, t], y] /. y -> 0) == 0, 
       v[x, 4000000, t] == 0, v[x, 0, t] == 0}

ics= {D[T[x, y, 0], y] == 0.41 g ρ[x, y, 0] T[x, y, 0]/P[x, y, 0], 
      D[P[x, y, 0], y] == g ρ[x, y, 0], T[x, y, 0] == 5770, 
      ρ[x, y, 0] == 1.42*10^-7*1.408*10^3}

NDSolve[Join[{eqns,bcs,ics}, {u, v, T, ρ}, {x, 0, 12000000}, {y, 0, 4000000}, {t, 0, 100}]
```

However, this then gives an error to say that you can't include $u_y$ in the boundary conditions as the equations don't include a higher order derivative in $y$ (i.e. $u_{yy}$). If you remove these derivatives, it gives a different error. I suspect that you need to tell Mathematica explicitly which method you want it to use to discretize your equations, and it would be very sensible to nondimensionalise properly (i.e. don't have your $x$ and $y$ ranges go up to the millions).